# background-image not work in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, google-chrome

```
  .button {
        background: transparent url("/assets/LoD-Button-Normal.png") no-repeat bottom right;
        width: 110px;
        height: 30px;
        display: block;
        background-position: bottom right; 
        text-align:center;
    }

    .button_click { 
      background: transparent url("/assets/LoD-Button-Click.png") no-repeat bottom right;
      width: 110px;
      height: 30px;
      display: block;
      background-position: bottom right;
    }

    $(".button").click(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("button").addClass("button_click");   
    })

    <a class="button" href="/link"> Button </a>
```

when I click button. it change background image on firefox but it not work on chrome. please help me

Comment: Works in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3JpLy/. Did you get any error logs in your console in Chrome? (Press F12 to bring it in front)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QAUaz/ seems to work fine...

Comment: what happens? does the changing of the class itself work and the background image is not shown (wrong Url?) or does the change of the class not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems to be fine so absent of any errors it could be that chrome is redirecting before it is changing the bg image.

Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass("button").addClass("button_click");
  location.href = $(this).attr('href'); 
  // if for some reason this isn't working you can call setTimeout with the location.href
});
```